# Is there a python version of JavaScript's String.fromCharCode?

Tags: python

`String.fromCharCode` returns a string based on a list of unicode codepoint values. @see [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)

Is there an analog in Python ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use this: `''.join(map(unichr, lst))`

Example:

```
''.join(map(unichr, [65,66,67])) # outputs ABC
```

Comment: +1. For an equivalent function taking a variable number of arguments: `def from_char_code(*args): return ''.join(map(unichr, args))`.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [chr()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#chr) or [unichr()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#unichr) for unicode values.